# intellij 2017.2 IDE not able to compile jdk 9

Tags: intellij-idea

I am struggling to get new JDK 9 working with intellij 2017.2 . I tried pretty much everything, but looks like its not picking java.base module because of which i am getting compile error for even String and System classes .

My project is very simple .

Any suggestions ?

[image]

Comment: Try removing JDK configuration in IntelliJ IDEA and add it again. Make sure IDE recognizes the classpath of the JDK installation correctly.

Comment: Thanks , it did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Usually it helps to remove JSDK configuration in IntelliJ IDEA Project Structure | SDKs dialog and then add it again.